# Outlet inside a wall behind TV

Tags: television

I purchased a TV for our bathroom remodel that is to be flush mounted in the wall - my question is can I install an outlet inside the wall to power the unit. It would be accessible if I lift the tv (it is gravity seated - no bolts - just lift it up to pull tv off wall).

So since code is that it must be accessible without demolition - would this be within code?

Here is a picture of what it looks like installed and a link to the install instructions which are vague at best.

[image: Watervue TV Pic]

[image: My installed TV]
[Watervue TV install][3]

Comment: That's cool. Watching TV in the tub is a little more understandable than the shower.

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problem, as long as the box and everything else is installed according to code. Since it's in the bathroom, GFCI protection is required.

Answer (score 1):

The National Electrical Code requires that it be accessible.

The definition of accessible is:

> **Accessible** (as applied to wiring methods). Capable of being removed or exposed without damaging the building structure or finish or not permanently closed in by the structure or finish of the building.

By this definition your installation would be acceptable. As Tester said the receptacle needs to be protected by GFCI.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer - every thing installed just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can get recessed receptacles for behind TVs. 
[Arlington TV receptacle with low-voltage plate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003E48COU)

Keep in mind, photos like you show have little regard for reality. They will put their products in the best light, regardless if it is actually possible or not.

As Tester says, this will need to be GFI protected, and the GFI must remain readily accessible. This means it cannot be behind the TV. You'll need to put a GFI somewhere else in the room, or use a blank-face GFI somewhere, or GFI protect the whole circuit at the breaker.

Comment: Thanks  -Installed the TV - the circuit is GFI protected - posted new pic above.